# What methods are there for a text-field to grab focus? (current method doesn't work in IE7)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Zhe Input field:

```
    <input id="category_name" name="category[name]" size="30" type="text">
```

Code that focuses the text field: (works in chrome, ff, and safari (only browsers I've tested so af)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("category_name").focus();
    </script>
```

Comment: is the script below the `<input>` in the HTML source?

Comment: yes, it is. That's correct placement, I beleieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well: setTimeout didn't work, just like callbacks and jQuery deferred.

The solution I came up with is (with jQuery):

```
$( "#inputId" ).focus().focus();
```

2x focus. Works without any drawback everywhere I tested.

Edit:

Also make sure that the input being focused is visible.
IE will throw an exception otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try either calling `focus()` in the body.onload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus()
    {
        document.getElementById("category_name").focus();
    }
</script>

<body onload="setFocus();">
    <!-- ...snip... -->
</body>
```

or doing this:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("category_name").focus(); }, 1);
```